# Handle activity get destroyed in Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigation, back-stack

When turning on "Don't keep activities in the Android developer options, the navigation route stack of Flutter app seems to be cleared and the Android app shows the first screen like a fresh start.

What is the proper way to keep or restore the navigation route stack in Flutter Android app?

Comment: little unclear of what you exactly want..?

Comment: I want to know how to store navigation stack when activity got destroyed in Android. Flutter framework seems have no built-in support for this problem. I think the only way now is using callback in activity life cycles to manually store the navigation stack and restore when activity reborn.

Comment: get stuck in this problem too.

Comment: @M.Plant: I think we should forget about this problem. Need to accept that we can't apply all Android knowledge to Flutter. You can think that the Flutter screen is not extended from Android Activity so it doesn't need to follow the Android Activity Lifecycle & Navigation Stack

Comment: @h0102 Did you get any solution for that, I have the same problem in my assignment. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't depend on the Screen to retain the displayed data since this can be destroyed. You can explore app state management available in Flutter. Using provider plugin is one of the simple ways of managing app state as demonstrated in this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

As for tracking the Navigation history, you can keep track of it in a `List<String>` if you're using [named routes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes).